# Como converter string para FileImageSource(Icon) Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Como converter uma `string`(Image) para `FileImageSource`(Icon) ?

Preciso exibir uma foto no `ToolbarItems` no canto direito do menu hamburger.

Tentei dessa forma, porém não funcionou.
Meu código:

```
FileImageSource IconFoto = new FileImageSource();

IconFoto = Foto; // Imagem retornada do BD como string

this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("nome", IconFoto, () =>
{
}, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que sua "string" seja um base 64 , sendo assim :

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add (new ToolbarItem () { Icon = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes))});
```

Comment: Tentei usar isso porém, dá erro de conversão de imagesource pra fileimagesource. Ai ele pede pra fazer um cast, ai faço o cast e na execução da erro de conversão.

Comment: sua string é uma base 64 ?